# Выдается ошибка и бот не может выдать роль в Discord Python

Tags: python, бот, discord

По задумке он должен с шансом 30% выдавать роль - раб, а с шансом 70% выдавать роль - Рабовладелец. Также выводить это в чат и снимать роль - Свободный. И могу ли я как-нибудь записать в базу данных человека с ролью - Рабовладелец? Например [Пользователь][Баланс].

```
import discord, asyncio, random, os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from bot_logic import *


description = '''An example bot to showcase the discord.ext.commands extension
module.

There are a number of utility commands being showcased here.'''

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%', description=description, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")

t_get_slave_role = 1191424500986826773 #Роль - Рабовладелец
t_slave_role = 1191424705287168092 #Роль - раб
t_clear_role = 1191427884116623531 #Роль - Свобоный человек

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    #Если бот зашел в сеть
    print(f'Бот {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id}), готов к работе!')
    print('------')

    channel = bot.get_channel(1191416150454710325) # ID Канала где игра
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Немного боте о Slaves", color=(1))
    emb.add_field(name="Привет! Я бот для игры 'Slaves'", value="Мой префикс для комманд - %\n Префикс это начало комманд, к примеру комманда - %help", inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
    await channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/bfp-black-flag-pirates-work-get-back-to-work-back-to-work-gif-6618814053542253714")
        

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(t_clear_role) #Роль - Свобоный человек
async def get_role(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    #Рандомно выдаём роль
    channel = bot.get_channel(1191416150454710325) # ID Канала где игра

    get_slave_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1191424500986826773) #Роль - Рабовладелец
    slave_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1191424705287168092) #Роль - раб
    clear_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1191427884116623531) #Роль - Свобоный человек

    role_shans = random.choice(30, 30, 30, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70)
    if role_shans == 70:
        await channel.send(f'{member} - раб') 
        await member.add_roles(get_slave_role)
    elif role_shans == 30:
        await channel.send(f'{member} - Рабовладелец') 
        await member.add_roles(slave_role)
    await member.remove_roles(clear_role)

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    #Инфа о боте
    channel = bot.get_channel(1191416150454710325) # ID Канала где игра
    emb1 = discord.Embed(title="Немного боте о Slaves", color=(1))
    emb1.add_field(name="Привет! Я бот для игры 'Slaves'", value="Мой префикс для комманд - %\n Префикс это начало комманд, к примеру комманда - %help", inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=emb1)
    await channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/bfp-black-flag-pirates-work-get-back-to-work-back-to-work-gif-6618814053542253714")
    

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    #Help
    channel = bot.get_channel(1191416150454710325) # ID Канала где игра
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Комманды Slaves", color=(1))
    emb.add_field(name="  Общие команды", value="")
    emb.add_field(name="%help", value="Выводит информацию о командах", inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name="%info", value="Информация о боте", inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name="%get_role", value="Информация о боте", inline=False)

    emb.add_field(name="  Команды раба", value="")

    emb.add_field(name="  Команды Рабовладельца", value="")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)


bot.run("Token")
```

Ошибка

```
2024-01-02 03:45:03 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command get_role
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AdminZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\AdminZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1021, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\AdminZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 938, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\AdminZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 845, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param, attachments)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AdminZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Сегодня у многих ясновидящий шар не работает, поэтому добавьте в вопрос саму ошибку и ее стек трейс. В базу данных записать можно все, главное понимать , что записывать и куда.